# cURL post 2 files as parameters

Tags: curl

I need to make a curl to an end point which is a post and what im unable to do is send 2 files as parameters.  What I'm able todo is send the files in the body. Here is how I do it:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/html" -F "data=@index.html" -F "data2=@test-result.xml" http://localhost:8280/reports
```

Any pointers on how to send the file contents as paramteres?

Comment: That command line sends two files in the multipart formpost, in the fields named "data" and "data2". You need to explain more what the problem is. Oh, and you don't want `-X POST` in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
curl -F 'data=@/path/to/index.html' -F 'data2=@/path/to/test-result.xml' http://localhost:8280/report
```